# psql installation on linux requires systemd

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, systemd, amazon-emr

I am installing psql on my AWS EMR (EC2 instance) which is Amazon Linux (not Amazon Linux 2).

I am getting an error after running the command

```
sudo yum install -y postgresql10

Error: Package: postgresql10-10.7-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg10)
           Requires: systemd
```

Amazon Linux 2 comes with systemd but AWS EMR doesn't support Amazon Linux 2.

How can I install psql client on AWS EMR?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install these packages on Amazon Linux or on Amazon Linux 2. They are designed and built for CentOS/RHEL 7. Use those distributions instead.

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 contains these packages by default. In Amazon Linux AMI these can't be installed.

Comment: It doesn't guaranteed to work on Amazon Linux 2 either. If it does work, it's accidental and will break in future.

Comment: It worked and I checked it too

Comment: Maybe it works today. But it cannot be guaranteed to work next week or next month. Then you will be stuck with a broken database after you've already gone into production.